# How to create a stored procedure in Postgres and return value?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in PostgreSQL. I have this script to create a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Duplicate_config_v1 (sourcequoteid IN int, sourceconfig IN varchar, destinationquote IN int, scenarioid IN int, flag INOUT varchar(10))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT
        Status::varchar(10)
    FROM
        public.duplicate_scenario_statuses
    WHERE
        id = 1;
    --returning 'Sucess'into flag;
END
$$;
```

I created the stored procedure as shown above. In the procedure I am passing few input parameters and returning some value from table. I am trying to call procedure as below

```
Call duplicate_config_v1(1,'1'::varchar(10),1,1);
```

Whenever I execute this statement, I get an error:

> ERROR: procedure duplicate_config_v1(integer, character varying, integer, integer) does not exist
> LINE 14:  Call duplicate_config_v1(1,'1'::varchar(10),1,1);
> ^
> HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 592

Comment: Why not just use a function?

Comment: Since I am calling stored procedure from efcore and there is a limitation with efcore that It can return only dbset

Comment: No idea what a "dbset" is, but a function can return a "set" as well (you use it like this: `select * from my_function(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use function.
In manual **43.6.3.** Calling a Procedure the example is something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE triple(INOUT x int)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    x := x * 3;
END;
$$;
```

that is very simple, then you can call the procedure to get the value.

---

**manual 43.6.2. Returning from a Procedure**

> A procedure does not have a return value. A procedure can therefore
> end without a RETURN statement. If you wish to use a RETURN statement
> to exit the code early, write just RETURN with no expression.
>
> If the procedure has output parameters, the final values of the output
> parameter variables will be **returned to the caller**.

Meaning, that the value will return to the caller, but you need extract step to get it. That's why when " case if return value" people recommend function.

---

the following demo use [DO COMMAND](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) to get the value from caller.

```
CREATE temp TABLE duplicate_scenario_statuses (
    id int,
    sourcequoteid int,
    sourceconfig text,
    destinationquote int,
    status text,
    scenarioid int,
    flag text
);

INSERT INTO duplicate_scenario_statuses (id, status)
    VALUES (1, 'hello');

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pg_temp.Duplicate_config_v1 (sourcequoteid IN int, sourceconfig IN text, destinationquote IN int, scenarioid IN int, flag OUT text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT
        status INTO flag
    FROM
        duplicate_scenario_statuses
    WHERE
        id = 1;
END
$$;

DO $$
DECLARE
    _status text;
BEGIN
    CALL pg_temp.Duplicate_config_v1 (1, '1', 1, 1, _status);
    RAISE NOTICE '_status: %', _status;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to call this SP?

Comment: also I am integrating with ef core. the limitation with efcore is that result should be dbset(table) not just value as per below document https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: just use function. Things would so much easier.

Comment: Like My answer said, you need call stored procedure in another DO command block.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is defined with 5 parameters, but you only provide 4. Thus the procedure definition is not found and your CALL results in " No procedure matches the given name and argument types".

You need to provide a dummy value for the inout parameter, e.g. NULL:

```
call duplicate_config_v1(1,'1',1,1,null);
```

To "return" a value, just [assign](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) it:

```
flag := 'Success';
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=541ed9e75d692f7fde845b698d091477)